# Mule http-proxy doesn't handle 401

Tags: mule, esb, http-proxy

I have a simple http proxy

```
<pattern:http-proxy name="http-proxy-sample"
    transformer-refs="request-transformer" inboundAddress="http://0.0.0.0:16809/"
    responseTransformer-refs="response-transformer" outboundAddress="${appnode.host}/xyz/api/" />
```

This handles all the requests and responses correctly except those with status 4xx. In case of 4xx responses it gives a 500 Internal server error instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to write a custom transformer, put it under responseTransformer, and handle(propagate,change) any exceptions there

Comment: Writing my own transformer doesn't solve the problem of mule not forwarding http response status properly in case of proxies.

Comment: write a bug report then, not a question on stackoverflow

Comment: I do agree @secario. Just not sure if i'm using it right.

Answer (score 2):

Add this property: `exceptionOnMessageError="false"`

Comment: Where is this property added?  The http-proxy?

Comment: In pattern:http-proxy:
<pattern:http-proxy name="http-proxy-sample" transformer-refs="request-transformer" inboundAddress="http://0.0.0.0:16809/"
    responseTransformer-refs="response-transformer" outboundAddress="${appnode.host}/xyz/api/" 
exceptionOnMessageError="false" />